# How to force useState to update state immediately?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Behaviour: the Empty result appears for a split second after the loading is done even if there is data.

Expected Behaviour: It should show content after loading and the empty result shouldn't appear.

Can I force setData to update state quicker than setLoading? Or is there any way to work around it?

```
export const SomePage = () => {
  const [Data, setData] = useState<Data>();
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
     setLoading(true);
     try{

       //getting data...

       const dataRes = await sendGetDataRes(something);
       setData(dataRes);

     } catch(err){

       //catching error...

     } finally{

       setLoading(false);

     }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  },[getData]);

  if(Loading){
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }
  if(!Data){
    return <div>Empty Result!</div>
  }

  return{
    <div>some content...</div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should set Loader as `true` for initial value.

Here is an working example:

```js
export const SomePage = () => {
  const [Data, setData] = useState<Data>();
  const [Loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const dataRes = await sendGetDataRes(something);
      setData(dataRes);
    } catch (err) {
      //catching error...
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  if (Loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!Data) {
    return <div>Empty Result!</div>;
  }

  return <div>some content...</div>;
};
```